# i want to use github for my team what to do to connect other employee pc with my master branch for push pull same project data

Tags: android, github

**i want to  use GitHub for my team to work in same project.what to do to connect other employee  with my master branch for push/pull same project data**

Answer (score 0):

I found the basic tutorials on Youtube very enlightening, please see links below. They will take you through all the basic steps from setting up the repository through to pushing and pulling data from a hub.

This link is specific to GitHub Multiple user accounts:

https://help.github.com/articles/merging-multiple-user-accounts/

This one is a nice overview:

https://youtu.be/OqmSzXDrJBk

https://youtu.be/Y9XZQO1n_7c

https://youtu.be/HVsySz-h9r4

Comment: thank you but what setting i need to do  in other employee to push the code in my master branch ...i have already installed "git for windows" in their machine.now how they connect with my repository....?